# remove subject in if clause

Tags: conditional-constructions

I was reading a book, and I saw this sentence:

> They also contain a lot of fat and hydrocarbon which, if eaten in
>   quantity, can result in ...

I was wondering whether it is possible to remove subject from the if clause?

Comment: There is no subject in the if clause.

Comment: if Jack comes, we will go out. Jack is subject in this sentence. but in question's sentence, the subject of if clause has removed which I have never this before @anouk

Comment: Yes, the subject and the auxiliary verb "be" can be ellipted, where "if eaten in quantity" is understood as "if a lot of fat and hydrocarbon is eaten in quantity. The "if" expression (not a clause but a preposition phrase in my grammar) is thus a conditional adjunct.

Comment: @BillJ  I think "if they are eaten in quantity" is a conditional clause. There's no preposition there except the one within the clause ("in quantity").

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty "If" is a preposition, not a subordinator. Modern grammar thus logically  classifies it as a preposition phrase with the prep "if" as head and a declarative content clause as complement of "if". In this case, the complement clause is reduced but the basic structure is the same. ..

Comment: @BillJ, could you recommend the name of a book, or even a website, that explains that classification? Thanks.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty I can highly recommend _A Student's Introduction to English Grammar_ by Huddleston & Pullum. (Cambridge University Press). See here:[link](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Students-Introduction-English-Grammar/dp/0521612888)

Comment: @BillJ Thank you.